# Configure Elasticsearch to not highlight stopwords

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

Is it possible to configure Elasticsearch not to highlight stopwords which occur alone in the text ?

For example in the following text from Wikipedia, I want to highlight "the lord of the rings", "rings", or "lord", but I don't want Elasticsearch to highlight "of" or "the" if they occur alone.

> **The Lord of the Rings** is an epic high-fantasy novel written by English author J. R. R. Tolkien. **The** story began as a sequel to Tolkien's 1937 fantasy novel The Hobbit, but eventually developed into a much larger work. Written in stages between 1937 and 1949, **The Lord of the Rings** is one of **the** best-selling novels ever written, with over 150 million copies sold. **The** title **of** the novel refers to the story's main antagonist, the Dark **Lord** Sauron, who had in an earlier age created the One **Ring** to rule **the** other **Rings** **of** Power as **the** ultimate weapon ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [highlight_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#_highlight_query):

1. Use [_analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-analyzer.html#_example_output_4) to analysis *The Lord of the Rings* to get words without *stopwords*
2. Use `highlight_query`to search with *The Lord of the Rings* and no stop words from 1.

maybe like:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match": {
            "my_field": {
                "query": "The Lord of the Rings"
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "order" : "score",
        "fields" : {
            "my_field" : {
                "highlight_query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "content": {
                                    "query": "my words"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's good but how can i produce such highlight query programmatically ? it should contain "non stopword" words and the whole phrase "the lord of the rings"

Comment: I think you can use `stop` analyzer to analysis *words* and get *no stopwords* fro `highlight` query.

Comment: Dealing with the same issue. I tried this approach but it did not return any highlights. I did replace my_field correctly and made the two queries identical. Is there anything else that I should take into consideration?

Comment: @bjornvandijkman you can try to post a question with your mapping and text that you want to highlight.